# Proof details of Theorem 11.1 in Atiyah-Macdonald

Tags: commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-analysis, graded-modules

I have some trouble filling in the details of this proof from Atiyah-Macdonald. In this result, the authors assume what follows:

1) $A = \oplus_{n=0}^\infty A_n$ is a Noetherian graded ring, and therefore $A_0$ is Noetherian and $A$ is a finitely generated $A_0$-algebra, generated by $x_1, \ldots, x_s$ of degrees $k_1, \ldots, k_s$ respectively.

2) $M = \oplus_{n=0}^\infty M_n$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, so in particular $M$ is Noetherian and $M_n$ are finitely generated $A_0$-modules.

3) $\lambda$ is an additive function (so $\lambda(M) = \lambda(N) + \lambda(M/N)$ for $N \subset M$) from finitely generated $A_0$-modules to the positive integers.

4) Lastly $P(M,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(M_n)t^n$.

[image]

If $K_n, L_n$ are as in the proof, then I understand that $K = \oplus_n K_n$ and $L = \oplus_n L_n$ is the kernel and cokernel, respectively, of the homomorphism induced by multiplication by $x_s$. If $x_s$ has degree $k_s$, then that would mean $L = \oplus_n \dfrac{M_n}{x_sM_{n-k_s}}$ where $M_{n-k_s} = \{0\}$ for $n < k_s$ and so the first $k_s$ factors in the sum are simply $M_i$. In particular then $$P(L,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{k_s-1} \lambda(M_n)t^n + \sum_{n= k_s}^\infty \lambda(L_n)t^n.$$

After the authors set up the equations $$ \lambda(L_{n+k_s}) - \lambda(K_n) = \lambda(M_{n+k_s}) - \lambda(M_n) = 0$$ they multiply each such equation by $t^{n+k_s}$ and then sum over all $n$, which gives $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(L_{n+k_s})t^{n+k_s} - t^{k_s}P(K,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda(M_{n+k_s})t^{n+k_s} - t^{k_s}P(M,t).$$ But now adding to both sides $\sum_{n=0}^{k_s-1} \lambda(M_n)t^n$ would make me obtain $$P(L,t) - t^{k_s}P(K,t) = (1-t^{k_s})P(M,t)$$ which is not correct since the authors obtain a difference of a polynomial $g(t)$. I can't seem to find my mistake. What exactly is $g(t)$ in that equation?

Also, I have another short question, which is related, about proposition 11.3 in the same book. $d(M)$ denotes here the pole at $t=1$ of $P(M,t)$.

[image]

The equation (2) becomes $(1-t^{k_s})P(M,t) = P(L,t) + g(t)$. Then I see that the pole of $P(L,t) + g(t)$ is of degree one less than the degree of the pole of $P(M,t)$, but how does one conclude $d(L) = d(M) - 1$ in this case?

Comment: There must be something simple that I am missing here. Given sequences $0 \rightarrow K_n \rightarrow M_n \xrightarrow{x_s} M_{n+k_s} \rightarrow L_{n+k_s} \rightarrow 0$ I would have that $L_{n+k_s} = M_{n+k_s}/x_sM_n$ by exactness. But then what do I take for $L_n$ where $n = 0, 1, \ldots, k_s-1$? I understood that $L$ is the cokernel of the map on $M$ given by multiplication by $x_s$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a careful checking of the proof I've to admit that *you* are right: $g(t)=0$. If you want more support, please check [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=tLEyb4qhaRoC&pg=RA2-PA8&lpg=RA2-PA8&dq=theorem+hilbert+serre+%22P%28M,t%29%22&source=bl&ots=h6NlLwIMqZ&sig=0NX4SCu89cUOLhEh7FL66CiVlFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CgbrUdaVOMqLOYuegZAD&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=theorem%20hilbert%20serre%20%22P%28M%2Ct%29%22&f=false) or [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~milicic/Eprints/chapter_1.pdf).

Now the answer to your second question becomes obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much for these references. I was very confused, as for example Lang seems to give the same proof as AM and there $g(t)$ also appears. I'll go through the proofs in the links you posted in the morning and then accept your answer.

Comment: @Malman Lang has copied the proof of AM word by word.